How can I set custom PhysicalNamingStrategy in runtime in Spring Boot 3, Hibernate 6?
UPD: This question IS NOT duplicate!
There is a question (Hibernate: Data Object with a dynamic table name by Annotations) that has a little bit similar problems but it has too old solution (12 y.o. question lol) so I think there should be more pretty solution for Hibernate 6 and Spring Boot 3, without usung .xml config and so on. Not to tell that solution in the question above uses extremely deprecated services
I use Java 17, Spring Boot 3.3.3, Hibernate 6.2.7 and PostgreSQL DB
I have a table like this
CREATE TABLE book(
        id uuid primary key not null,
        name text unique not null,
        type varchar(50) not null
);

Also I have many materialized views of this table, it all have the same structure but different conditions, such as:
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIES kids_book as
SELECT*
FROM book
WHERE
    type IN ('tail', 'poems')
);

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIES poets_book as
SELECT*
FROM book
WHERE
    type IN ('poems', 'poet_biography')
);

etc.

So in my Java code I need an @Entity class for each of views. But I need an ability to create new views in runtime and process them in the code so I want to use one @Entity class for all of these views and only change the table's name.
For solving this problem I have overrided PhysicalNamingStrategy:
public class MyNamingStrategy extends PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl {

    private Identifier tableName;

    public MyNamingStrategy(String tableName){
        this.tableName= Identifier.toIdentifier(tableName);
    }

    @Override
    public Identifier toPhysicalTableName(Identifier logicalName, JdbcEnvironment context) {
        if(logicalName.getText().equalsIgnoreCase(BOOKVIEW)){
            return tableName;
        }
        return logicalName;
    }
}

So I want to change tables' names in all @Entity classes than have @Table(BOOKVIEW) annotation.
If have this entity
@Entity
@Table(name = BOOKVIEW)
public class MyBookViewEntity{
// ...
}

I want to process it like this:
// If I want to load books from kids_book
sessionFactory.setPhysicalNamingStrategy(new MyNamingStrategy("kids_book"));
sessionFactory.openSession();
entityManager.createQuery("SELECT * FROM kids_book", MyBookViewEntity.class)
/...

// If I want to load books from poets_book 
sessionFactory.setPhysicalNamingStrategy(new MyNamingStrategy("poets_book "));
sessionFactory.openSession();
entityManager.createQuery("SELECT * FROM poets_book", MyBookViewEntity.class)
}

// or maybe use dynamic JpaRepository if it is possible

And map all of this queries to the same entity class because of all of theese views have same structure
But I cannot find how to configure SessionFactory in runtime
I know that I can define my custom PhysicalNamingStrategy in application.properties like this:
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.physical_naming_strategy="path to my definition"

but in this case I cannot change this strategy in runtime
There is a question (Hibernate: Data Object with a dynamic table name by Annotations) that has a little bit similar problems but it has too old solution (12 y.o. question lol) so I think there should be more pretty solution for Hibernate 6 and Spring Boot 3, without usung .xml config and so on

I'm afraid you have to create new Spring context for each new session factory. It will be bumpy road. Didn't you consider using native queries? Or some sort of SQL magic where you pass actual view through extra property?

You didn't mention what DB do you use?

@talex postgres

I hope if there is an elegant solution using custom bean postprocessing or smth :))

Elegant solution would be to use partitioning in DB :)

Also I found that, but it contains some highly questionable magic.
